# Plotting or visualizating cohort analysis (triangular) data in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Consider the following cohort analysis data table:

[image: Cohort Table]

Derived from this data:

```
df <- structure(list(cohort = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L), wk = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L), value = c(24L, 12L, 10L, 5L, 2L, 75L, 43L, 11L, 14L, 97L, 35L, 12L, 9L, 4L, 5L), flag = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("cohort", "wk", "value", "flag"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

What are some ways to elegantly plot this data in `R`?

**Attempt 01**
*Not rotated correctly, but easy to create - difficult to interpret for those use to the format in the picture above*

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = wk, y = cohort, fill = factor(flag))) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), color = "white")
```

[image: Attempt 01]

Comment: you can add `+scale_y_reverse()` to your first call

Comment: @jeremycg Thank you! Not sure how I missed that very simple solution - do you know if `ggplot2` every implemented being able to place the x-axis on top or this still a `ggvis`-only feature? If you write an answer, I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @jeremycg's comment above - adding `scale_y_reverse()` works wonderfully:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = wk, y = cohort, fill = factor(flag))) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), color = "white") +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image: Cohort Visual]